# Hive QL regular expression for accepting only string and numbers but no special characters

Tags: regex, hiveql

I am trying to write a regex in Hive to identify all of the records that have just a string/numeric (might include decimals) with no special characters

Here's my code:

```sql
select Loan item,
case when 'Loan_item' rlike '([a-zA-Z]{1,30}\s*)+'
then 
    'pass'
else
    'fail'
end as test
from loanitem_vw
```

result:

```
City tax - pass
dgdgshd - pass
dfhsdshj - pass
? - pass
""" - pass
```

How do I exclude the special characters in this case?

Comment: What is a "special character"? Do you mean you wish to determine if a string contains only letters or substrings that are representations of floats and integers? If so, you could say that and make no mention of "special characters". `{1,30}` in your regex seems to reflect an unstated requirement; `\s*` seems to contradict your earlier statement concerning allowed characters.

Comment: Hey Cary, Thank you. You are right. I meant I wish to determine if a string contains just letters that can range from one to 30 characters. I removed the \s* from my regex and it seems to work fine. However...for the 5th example with just double quotes that result should be a "fail" since it's not a string. The altered regex fails to determine that. How do you suggest I change that? @Cary Swoveland

Comment: Presumably, the last example is a string comprised of the three double quotes, which does not match the regex `^[a-zA-Z]{30}$`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UhhXHs/1/). I don't understand how you can say `City tax` passes, as it contains a character other than a letter, or why the next two examples pass, considering that they do not contain 30 letters.